# ¿Como hacer que un WebView guarde las paginas web que carga?

Tags: cache, navegador-web, webview-android

Tengo una aplicación en Android en la que un webView carga 3 webs distintas dependiendo de  3 botones en la interfaz de la aplicación, me gustaría que al pulsar otro de los botones si la pagina se ha cargado antes no se vuelva a cargar

Ya he intentado usar

```
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
                     mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(8 * 1024 * 1024); 
                    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
                    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
                    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
                    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT); 
                    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) { 
                    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
                    }
```

[image: Pantalla Principal de la app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pondré une ejemplo que me funcionó hace mucho, este `WebView` mostraba una imagen de un sitio (Gracias a una respuesta de @Elenasys que mezclé código de ella y otros en S.O :p)

```
 webview = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loadImagePortada);

        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(5 * 1024 * 1024); // 5MB
        webview.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getActivity().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);

        if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { // Cargando sin conexión
            webview.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY );

        }
        final AlertDialog dialogoAlerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();

        progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Cargando portada", "Espere por favor...");

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


                view.loadUrl(url);

                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                dialogoAlerta.setTitle("Error");
                dialogoAlerta.setMessage(description + " Intente mas tarde por favor.");
                dialogoAlerta.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        return;
                    }
                });
                dialogoAlerta.show();
            }
        });


        webview.loadUrl("http://mispruebas.eshost.com.ar/getimage.php");

 private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }
```

La primera vez que abría la actividad me cargaba desde la web, cuando salía de esa actividad y mas tarde volvía a entrar ya no me la descargaba, cargaba desde el cache.

Es une ejemplo muy funcional ;)

Answer (score 2):

Cada uno de los 3 botones realiza la carga de una URL diferente en un WebView, si deseas guardar caché usa el metodo `setCacheMode()` de [`android.webkit.WebSettings`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) usando la constante

> **`LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK`** Usa recursos en caché cuando están disponibles, aun si han expirado.

Ejemplo:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

Como otra opción podrías usar la constante `LOAD_CACHE_ONLY`:

> **`LOAD_CACHE_ONLY`** No usa la red, carga de caché.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Ya había intentado eso antes, pero mi `WebView` sigue cargando las paginas que ya ha cargado anteriormente, esas lineas de código las tengo colocadas en el `onCreate` después de definir el `WebView` y antes de usar el método `.load(url)`.